# Spring KeyCloak receiving always 401 while in Docker container

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, spring-security, keycloak

I'm facing a problem where when I put my Spring Boot application into Docker container I always receive 401 status code when hiting secured endpoint with valid JWT.

When Spring Boot application is running normally (not in Docker container) everything works fine.

Could not find anything useful in application logs.

Here's part of application-docker.yaml:

```yaml
security:
  oauth2:
    resourceserver:
      jwt:
        issuer-uri: http://${KEYCLOAK_URL}:8080/realms/polsl-course-api
```

Here's docker-compose.yaml:

```yaml
keycloak:
  container_name: 'keycloak'
  hostname: keycloak
  image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
  environment:
    DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
    DB_ADDR: keycloak-postgres
    DB_DATABASE: keycloak
    DB_USER: root
    DB_SCHEMA: public
    DB_PASSWORD: root
    KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
    KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
  ports:
    - '8000:8080'
  depends_on:
    - keycloak-postgres
  command:
    - start-dev

schedule-service:
  container_name: schedule-service
  build:
    context: schedule-service
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  environment:
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: docker
    RABBITMQ_PASSWORD: password
    RABBITMQ_USERNAME: user
    RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbitmq
    EUREKA_NAME: discovery-server
    EUREKA_PORT: 8761
    POSTGRES_URL: schedule-service-postgres
    POSTGRES_USERNAME: root
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
    KEYCLOAK_URL: keycloak
  ports:
    - '8089:8089'
  depends_on:
    - rabbitmq
    - schedule-service-postgres
    - keycloak
```

What could be cause of such a problem?

Comment: What is the exact value of the `iss` claim in your access tokens (you can use something like https://jwt.io to read token claims)

Comment: It is: http://localhost:8000/realms/polsl-course-api

Comment: Do you suggest that until `iss` isn't `keycloak:8080/realms/polsl-course-api` the requests won't be authorized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri` in your Spring configuration must match **exactly** the value of `iss` claim in access tokens (scheme and trailing slash, if any, are important).

You can define the `hostname` property in Keycloak configuration. This should impact the hostname in issuer URI for all tokens.

You can also define the `jwk-set-uri` in properties if it can't be guessed from `issuer-uri` (for instance when the host of the issuer URI can not be resolved / reached from your resource-server network)